# JavaMail: MimeMessage sent as plain text when HTML is expected?

Tags: java, html, email, jakarta-mail, mime-types

I have the following `Java` code in my `Spring` REST Web App:

**Code:**

```
@Service("Mailer")
public class Mailer {

    private final JavaMailSender mailSender;

    private void send(final Email email){

        MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();

        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
        helper.setFrom(address);
        helper.setTo(email.to());
        helper.setSubject(email.subject());

        helper.setText(email.content(), true); //is this correct?

        mailSender.send(mimeMessage);

    }

}
```

**MimeMessageHelper setText():**

```
public void setText(String text, boolean html) throws MessagingException {
        Assert.notNull(text, "Text must not be null");
        MimePart partToUse;
        if (isMultipart()) {
            partToUse = getMainPart();
        }
        else {
            partToUse = this.mimeMessage;
        }
        if (html) {
            setHtmlTextToMimePart(partToUse, text);
        }
        else {
            setPlainTextToMimePart(partToUse, text);
        }
    }
```

My code sends an email as expected but when I receive it - it is in **pain text**.

I.e. the `HTML` is not rendered in the email body and the email starts with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
...
```

How can I ensure that the email is sent and rendered as `HTML` not plain text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the MimeMessage content directly like this.

```
mimeMessage.setContent(email.content(), "text/html");
mimeMessage.saveChanges();
```